# Export Crystal Report To Excel - Specify Directory

Tags: c#, excel, crystal-reports

I have crystal reports (using C#) that I pull and want to export to Excel. I manage to pull and export the report just fine. But in the code I manually specify the export directory.

Code:

```
myEquipCalRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, "C:\\Temp\\ReportName.xls");
```

I know the path must be a string value. How can I ask the user where he/she wants to export the report to (and give it a name) instead of manually specifying the path in the code?

I tried using "SaveFileDialog" with the code below and then I get this exception: "*Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.*". This allows the user to specify a file name, although I noticed the file type just below the file name box is not set, and have no types to select from either.

```
SaveFileDialog browser = new SaveFileDialog();
string directoryPath = "";
ienter code here`f (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   directoryPath = browser.ToString(); // prints path
}
myEquipCalRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, directoryPath);
```

If I use "FolderBrowserDialog", I get the error: "*Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Directory' is denied.*" which I suspect is due to only giving a directory path, but no file name.

```
FolderBrowserDialog browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
string directoryPath = "";

if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    directoryPath = browser.SelectedPath; // prints path
}
myEquipCalRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, directoryPath);
```

If I try the following, I get no error, but also no file is saved:

```
FolderBrowserDialog browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
string directoryPath = "";
string FileName = "ExcelExport.xls";
string Path = directoryPath + FileName;

if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
directoryPath = browser.SelectedPath; // prints path
}

myEquipCalRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, Path);
```

Also, how can I export to .xlsx instead of .xls? I can specify the extension in the path as .xlsx, but it does not want to open. Need to remove the X at the end to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code to get the path correct as the path was given through as **"System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog: Title: , FileName: C:\Temp\test.xls"** and not **"C:\Temp\test.xls"** with all the dialog boxes.

```
            SaveFileDialog browser = new SaveFileDialog();
            string directoryPath = "";
            if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                directoryPath = browser.FileName.ToString();
            }
```

And the you can use one of these lines to write the file, depending on which way you chose to use export the report:

```
myRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, "C:\\Temp\\AMCMaintTempExcelReportFile.xls")

CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = directoryPath;

myRPT.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, directoryPath);
```